# Which Function/Layout i need to use to obtaint the following view in android

Tags: android, layout

I have task as shown in the  image
[image: I want like this]

The horizontal scroll view contains set of buttons for ex:- 11 buttons, when 1 is clicked it will contain a data which need to retrieve from the server side and it should be arranged as the below(i.e only four circles per window later we need to either scroll them or swipe window to view remaining). The Horizontal scroll view is static, but the beneath of it is dynamic and how to arrange them please give me suggestion. I tried of linear layout but it didn't worked. Sorry for poor English. As i am new to android i can't made it. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: one question,position of this four images are fixed?

Comment: @Techfist ya the should be fixed.. but in a scroll view or swipe only.. why negative rating.. did i asked wrong?

Comment: Any One Please Help me in this Regard......

Comment: Hi, Tortoise Walker were you able to solve the issue, sorry was cought up with other work, if its not done yet I will try to solve it for you.

Comment: Hi, Techfist.. I am sorry for late reply.. i tried it a bit.. but it also not worked.. if you don't mind please guide me....

Comment: alright, let me try implementing it.

Comment: Ok Techfist... Thank you

Comment: posted my logic, read am let me know in case it confuses you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this is just an crude implementation you have to refine it by yourself, but this will be enough to generate what you want. I will explain it in pieces.

Step 1: save this as a drawable, in your drawable folder name it something like circle_bcg.xml, this will generate circle background for views

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="360"
        android:endColor="#FFFF0000"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000" />

</shape>
```

Step 2: As your need is to display four Images beneath a list of horizontally scrollable buttons, we will create a different Cell layout which will have four images arranged in the way you want, for all of them background will be set us circle background above. define below in a separate layout say hcell_view.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bcg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bcg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bcg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_bcg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 3: Now, as horizontal layout will contains a series of button lets define a separate layout for holding look and feel  of our button, save below in another separate xml file say `button_view.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="press" >

</Button>
```

Step 4: alright, now we are done with all our basic components, now we will define our main layout which will hold all of them together, this is your main layout which has to be set a content layout for your activity. It contains this components, a HorizontalScroll view which will hold dynamically inflated buttons, and a ViewGroup (LinearLayout) which will display View defined in step 2, when any of button is clicked.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hviewButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hviewCircle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Yes after doing this you are all set, you have required view display logic in your hand, lets now test this, below Activity code will generate view similar to your original image when a button is pressed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewGroup hViewButton;
    private ViewGroup hViewCircle;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        hViewButton = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hviewButton);
        hViewCircle = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.hviewCircle);

        // am assuming 10 button, you need to figure out 
        // actual number of button to be displayed.
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            Button button = (Button)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.button_view,
                    null, false);
            hViewButton.addView(button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    hViewCircle.removeAllViews();


                    View imageGroup = mInflater.
                            inflate(R.layout.hcell_view,hViewCircle,false);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    imageGroup.setLayoutParams(params);
                    hViewCircle.addView(imageGroup);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This concludes our basic implementation, now as you said later on this set of 4 images has to be scrolled either way, for doing this you can take the similar approach like we did with Buttons, you can have a separate HorizontalScrollView/ViewPager/ViewFlipper for holding group of images, count the number of images group need to displayed through to data retrieval logic, and user any of suggested widgets for displaying them as swappable views.

Comment: thanks for your support. I tried your's, but when we use weights, i have one problem. I am getting the four Images/screen dynamically.. So if suppose there were only three at server side, the above will align correctly but the below of them will be stretched na..? Because i tried it with three images then the second linear layout first button got stretched to the entire screen...

Comment: for that keep the fourth ImageView intact, just mark its Visibility as Invisible, this will result into no distortion in UI. I mean say if onle one Image is present mark rest three Invisible, other way yould be computing and assigning layout parms dynamically as well.